# Transfer data from aws s3 to gcs by using gsutil - SSL Certification Error

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I am trying to transfer data from AWS S3 to GCS. 
I changed the private key and secrete key in boto file and when I try the following command getting the error.

Command: gsutil ls s3://axz

Error Message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform/gsutil\gsutil", line 22, in 
    gsutil.RunMain()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gsutil.py", line 114, in RunMain
    sys.exit(gslib.**main**.main())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib__main__.py", line 383, in main
    perf_trace_token=perf_trace_token)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib__main__.py", line 577, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
    collect_analytics=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\command_runner.py", line 299, in RunNamedCommand
    return_code = command_inst.RunCommand()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\commands\ls.py", line 526, in RunCommand
    exp_dirs, exp_objs, exp_bytes = ls_helper.ExpandUrlAndPrint(storage_url)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\ls_helper.py", line 180, in ExpandUrlAndPrint
    print_initial_newline=False)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\ls_helper.py", line 252, in _RecurseExpandUrlAndPrint
    bucket_listing_fields=self.bucket_listing_fields):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\wildcard_iterator.py", line 476, in IterAll
    expand_top_level_buckets=expand_top_level_buckets):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\wildcard_iterator.py", line 157, in **iter**
    fields=bucket_listing_fields):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\boto_translation.py", line 380, in ListObjects
    for key in objects_iter:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\s3\bucketlistresultset.py", line 34, in bucket_lister
    encoding_type=encoding_type)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\s3\bucket.py", line 473, in get_all_keys
    '', headers, **params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\s3\bucket.py", line 399, in _get_all
    query_args=query_args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\s3\connection.py", line 668, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\connection.py", line 1071, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\connection.py", line 1030, in _mexe
    raise ex
**ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely comes from a difference between the SSL certificate bundles on your machines - that's generally been the issue for others that have encountered this error, e.g. https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1545

If you're unable to update your certificate bundle, you might also try explicitly disabling certificate validation (**be warned, this opens you up for man-in-the-middle attacks**) by setting the https_validate_certificates Boto option:

```
gsutil -o 'Boto:https_validate_certificates=False' [...]
```

**Edit:**
You might also want to try generating your own certificate bundle file via
https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/mk-ca-bundle.pl
and seeing if making gsutil use that will help:

```
gsutil -o 'Boto:ca_certificates_file=C:\path\to\ca-bundle.crt' [...]
```

Comment: Hi mhouglum, Thanks for your reply. I tried gsutil -o 'Boto:https_validate_certificates=False"  and i uninstall pip remove certifi as well but still getting same error.